# Where do you place a footer in react?

Tags: html, reactjs

I'm building an app off of the create-react-app starter pack. I can import the Footer component into my App.js before my React Router Switch for different pages... but the problem is that this places my footer into the body tag which isn't semantic html for machine readability purposes. Also, it feels wrong to stick it in the public index.html file. Any workarounds/solutions?

Comment: "this places my footer into the body tag which isn't semantic html for machine readability purpose" I don't know about "for machine readability purpose", but for valid HTML, all HTML to be displayed should be within the body tag.

Comment: When you say "body" tag, do you mean HTML `<body>`? Technically everything needs to go into `<body>`, including `<footer>`. https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_footer.asp